# How to get Useful crashlog information Android Cocos2dx C++

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, crash-dumps, android-logcat

I'm working in cocos2dx android using c++, java. I got crash on my device and looked in logcat and found what is attached. Crash log doesn't throw me any useful information at all. I tried on different devices and found out some devices throw me useful crash log and some devices doesn't. This log is the Galaxy SII log. Can some body help me how can i translate this log or get some how useful crash logs?

Note: Crashes particular happening in C++ face such issues. And i'm working in MacOS Eclipse.

You can find this log here as well

[CrashLog](https://docs.google.com/a/gaminations.com/document/d/1_1IIBF7wiiK0BykfXEX2mNnbRBXo4UIvDBO61DLlHpQ/edit)

[image]

Comment: It would be a good idead to put the log in your question in text format rather than as an image. For more info regarding crash dumps, see http://kobablog.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/how-to-read-crash-dump-of-android/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,
It's better to use CCLog/Printf Everywhere in cocos2d-x/c++ as its d best way of debug which I prefer.

Secondly, 
Update your eclipse with ADT 21 and native Development which provides native debug. After doing those setting just Debug your application with Android Native debug which makes life easier like you do it in your Xcode

Thirdly,
If you are making cross platform then surely you will have iOS or Windows project of the same.. So just check your core game code in Xcode/Visual Studio.. Once it is working there properly you can come to android I mean eclipse and then cross check you will be able to catch problem easily

Lastly,
Prefer eclipse the last option because it is lot buggier and android needs JNI class that makes the crashes to find more difficult... I prefer visual studio because it crashes even if the variable is not NULL where android takes it all ...
It is major difference of the string in all platform ....

And also if you could add your Log then I might be able to help you more...

Comment: thanks man, i have a link in my post "Crash Log" you can follow it to find my crash log. and trying to update my ADT and as well. https://docs.google.com/a/gaminations.com/document/d/1_1IIBF7wiiK0BykfXEX2mNnbRBXo4UIvDBO61DLlHpQ/edit

Comment: actually im implementing crash reporting so CCLog not useful as for debugging im already using CCLog.