# Getting fatal error 11 with cocos2d-X

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to run HelloWorld app with cocos2d-X in my android device. But when I run I get this error:

```
05-08 19:03:27.320: A/libc(9496): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 9509 (Thread-1859)
```

I tried to understand what this error means following this [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436383/how-to-check-crash-log-using-android-ndk-in-cocos2d-x), but I get that adb command is not found.

What should I do?

Comment: isn't cocos2d in C++ ? So probably better tagged C++ than Java?

Comment: Yes. I tagged with java because of android, but I already changed for c++

Comment: Most probably, the reason of the crashes is an unitialized class member or dereferencing of nullptr.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error on Android today, caused by `Label` creation.

When creating a `Label` on Android, you have to specify the path to the font, but on iOS, you only specify the name of the font.

I had only the iOS version implemented, so the app was crashing during Label creation.

Here's more info about custom fonts and Label creation:
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Use_Custom_TTF_Font_on_iOS